# jQuery Validation message colour

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery validation routine for my form, I've managed to highlight each control border in red - that was pretty easy.

I would like to display the messages returned for each error are shown in black, and I would like to change that to red - unfortunately I'm unable to find any useful information on how I would achieve this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("form").validate({
            errorClass: 'errors',
            rules: {
                txtWDUCI: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 13,
                },
                txtWDCAND: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4
                },
                txtWDCENT: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                mskWDQAN: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },
                mskWDLEAP: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4
                },
                drpWDSES: {
                    required: true
                },
                drpWDSYY: {
                    required: true
                },
                drpWDEXAM: {
                    required: true
                },
                drpWDBRD: {
                    required: true
                },
                mskSubj: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4
                },
                mskWDOPT: {
                    required: true
                },
                txtWDGRD1: {
                    required: true
                },
                txtWDGRD2: {
                    required: true
                },
            },
            messages: {
                txtWDUCI: {
                    required: "&nbsp;REQUIRED: UCI"
                },
                txtWDCAND: {
                    required: "&nbsp;REQUIRED: Candidate Number"
                },
                txtWDCENT: {
                    required: "&nbsp;REQUIRED: Centre Number"
                },
                mskWDQAN: {
                    required: "&nbsp;Required: QAN"
                },
                mskWDLEAP: {
                    required: "&nbsp;REQUIRED: LEAP"
                },
                drpWDSES: {
                    required: "&nbsp;REQUIRED: session"
                },
                mskSubj: {
                    required: "&nbsp;REQUIRED: Subject Code"
                },
                mskWDOPT: {
                    required: "&nbsp;REQUIRED: Option Code"
                },
                txtWDGRD1: {
                    required: "&nbsp;REQUIRED: GRADE 1"
                },
                txtWDGRD2: {
                    required: "&nbsp;REQUIRED: Grade 2"
                }

            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).parent().addClass('error')
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).parent().removeClass('error')
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `color: #FF0000;` ...

Comment: You should change the color in the CSS file

Comment: Thanks, I realise I need to use CSS to change the color - I'm not clear on where I need to insert to CSS to make the message appear in red.

Comment: Just to be clear: CSS is a whole different language. In your question, you have embedded JavaScript code in a `<script>` element. You can embed CSS rules in a similar way using a `<style>` element.

Answer (score 6):

On the Web, we use HTML to make a document, CSS to suggest how it should *look*, and JavaScript to suggest how it should *behave*.

Your Javascript is modifying the document ("DOM") to add a class called "error". You can use CSS rules to suggest colors, fonts, borders, spacing or whatever you want for those "error" elements:

```
   .error {
      color: red;
      background-color: #acf;
   }
```

Most modern browsers have a development toolkit which allows you to inspect an element and see the CSS rules browser has used when drawing that element. In my browser, I can use right-click then "Inspect Element". It might be something similar on yours.

Answer (score 2):

Use this css to change the text color of errors:

```
.error {
  color: #F00;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are parameters `errorClass`, `errorElement` and `errorContainer`. Did you try reading through the [Documentation?](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorclass)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the class "error" to the parent of the element with the error. By adding some CSS to the error class you can configure the text color, background color, border color, etc.

CSS:

```
.error {
  color: #F00;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

If the error class is already loaded with errors then add another class. If the class needs to be on the element (instead of the parent) just remove the .parent() call from your chain.